# Extend UISplitViewController?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, uisplitview

Is there a way to extend the functionality of UISplitViewController?
I would like to:

- Have a toolbar at bottom, common for both detail and master controller.
- Make the detailViewController behave as a UINavigationController, i mean push and pop other controllers on it and not to the whole screen space.
- Both controllers are visible in all UIInterfaceOrientation values. (I think this isn't supported)

Is this possible with the current UISplitViewController?

It would be better to build my own UIViewController and simulate the apparience and behavior of the UISplitViewController plus my extended functionality?

In case i decide choice 2, would that make my app rejected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check out Matt Gemmell's [MGSplitViewController](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController), which is an open source iOS split view controller with more features than `UISplitViewController`. Since its open source, it would probably be much easier to make said changes to this than to `UISplitViewController`.

Comment: My [custom UISplitViewController](http://iphone-dev-tips.alterplay.com/2011/05/custom-uisplitviewcontroller-for-ipad.html) is more limited, but less buggy. Check it out.